# I want to change the name on my email messages

Tags: gmail

How do I change this, please, from "John Smith" to just "John"?

Answer (score 2):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158?hl=en :

1. Select Settings.
2. Click the Accounts tab.
3. In the “Send mail as:”     section, locate the email address you'd like to edit.
4. Click edit
   info next to the address.
5. In the “Name:” section, specify what you’d
   like your name to be and click Save changes.